# How to solve java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: java, spring, servlets, struts2

I fond an error on my first steps into `struts framework`. Could anyone give me some hints based on that stacktrace?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast 
org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer to 
javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast
org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer to
javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
```

Comment: Since class `SpringServletContainerInitializer` implements interface `ServletContainerInitializer` this error might be caused by problems in your classpath. You should provide more information about what are you doing to help us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Cannot cast
Class A----->org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer to 
Interface B---->javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
```

***FOR EXAMPLE***

```
class A implements B{}
interface B{}
```

*And you are trying to perform something like this*

```
A objA=new A();
A t1=(B)objA;//<-----Not Allowed
B t2=(A)objA;//<-----Allowed
```